# build-time / compile-time decorators in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, decorator

I believe this is not in line with the purpose of `decorators` in TypeScript; however, is it possible to use decorators that changes the output `js` files depending on the circumstances?

**usecase 1:**

```ts
export class Foo {
  @debugMode
  private log() { /* implementation */ }
  public doSomething() {
    this.log(arguments);
  }
}
```

`@debugMode` decorator, in the build-time (gulp or ..), removes the method and its callers when building for production, so that there will be no sign of the implementation of this method in the output js file.

or

```
@debugMode
@Route('UC2')
export class UC1Page{ }
```

`@debugMode` will remove the class definition and its decorators completely from the output js when built in production.

or

```
// this is not a valid syntax, only for the purpose of the usecase
// can achieve the same behavior using the first example
@debugMode doSomethingWeird(blah, blah);
@releaseMode sendGoogleAnalyticsInfo(blah, blah);
```

The first line will be removed in production, whereas the second line will be removed in development environment.

**usecase 2 (not necessarily in AngularJS):**

Let's assume we have the following folder structure:

```
[uc2]
-- uc2-component.ts
-- uc2-component.html
-- uc2-component.css
```

and the following code in `app-component.ts`:

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'my-foo',
  styleUrls: ['very/long/path/to/this/folder/uc2/uc2.component.css'],
  templateUrl: 'very/long/path/to/this/folder/uc2/uc2.component.html'
})
export class UC2Component { }
```

Regardless of weather or not this is a bad practice, is it possible to pragmatically feed `templateUrl` and `styleUrl` with the correct path of the HTML and CSS files - since they share the directory? This is to avoid hard-coding the path of these files and therefore having freedom of changing the location of these 3 files (so that we only need to change the path for the import of the `ts` file) if needed.

Comment: Have you found any solution for usecase 2?